# Having 100 buttons..easy way how to call a method when any is pressed?

Tags: c#, events

I have not programmed in a while and currently there is a need to invoke a method when any of large number of buttons is clicked. I do not want to manually hook the OnLick event..is there any easier way? I am sure but cannot remember..
Thanks

Comment: which type of application winform or wpf

Comment: `OnLick event`?  What kind of program are you writing?  :-)

Comment: Create one big button with an image of 100 buttons on it.

Comment: Don't create the buttons individually.  Create them dynamically instead.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way achieve this:

```
List<Button> yourButtonList = new List<Button>( )
{
    button1,
    button2,
    [...]
    button100
};

foreach( var currentButton in yourButtonList )
{
    currentButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.YourClickHandler);
}

/***/

private void YourClickHandler( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all buttons in a groupbox, and find the controls in the groupbox, if the control is a button, you add event, so, whenever you create a new button in groupbox he already link the event

```
yourButtonList.AddRange( /* linq to get button controls for groupbox */ ) 

foreach( var currentButton in yourButtonList )
{
    currentButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.YourClickHandler);
}
```